# Render two layers together for compositing

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, compositing-nodes, layers

Hello blender community,

I am trying to learn the compositor in blender but I came across a small problem. I placed the environment in the first layer and the sun in the second (sky in both disabled) like you can see in the image.
I renderd both layers together by selecting the two layers.

**The problem is that I cannot see the sun in the compositor or when I render both layers together**

I did the same thing as the video showed so can somebody help me out?

I looked around in other similar question but that didn't help me

[image]

Comment: In the "sun" render layer preview it looks as there actually is something (probably the "sun-sphere" object unlit). What did you expect to see? Could you post a link to the video you mentioned?

Comment: @Carlo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fWcCkQ3943Y . I except to see a yellow sphere appearing above the hills. here an image of how the render looks now: http://puu.sh/mcr0M/dbd4c94e17.jpg  . Like you can see there is no sun but I selected both layers and in the none rendered view (right corner view on the image in the question) you can see the sun

Comment: Don't use add on a color mix node, but an alpha over node. See this post: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/38334/1853 or use the alpha information of the foreground layer as a factor on the mix node

Comment: The lamp (in this case sun) won't be seen in render even if it's there. Unticking Sky isn't the best way of overlaying 2 rendered images together, see http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1303/can-blender-render-pngs-with-the-background-transparent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

1) I needed to uncheck "use alpha" in the compositor. 
2) add an alpha over to combine two layers.

I only don't understand why?

[image]