# Objects appear mixed and transparent when compositing

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, layers

I am working on a sci-fi project, I rendered my scene and my objects are rendered on separate render layers. I encountered a problem and that is the spaceship and the planet in the scene both appeared mixed and transparent. I wanted to ask if maybe someone know a solution to this issue. Here is a picture of the compositing.[image]

Many thanks in advance

Comment: just a guess but check your render layers, you may have the wrong layers selected.

Comment: To control what layers go in front of others use Alpha over. See this link: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49049/my-objects-are-semi-transparent-and-not-one-behind-the-other-in-the-compositor/49137#49137 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38333/background-image-shows-in-front-of-3d-objects-not-behind-them/38334#38334

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to enable Transparency in the Render panel. This would allow you to composite your layers with more Alpha Over nodes instead of Add nodes. In general, I would keep Add nodes only for layering lighting effects.

Comment: Ok, great, pleas mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem.