# Why won't this particle system render?

Tags: rendering, particles

[image]

When I render my image, my particles system won't render, instead it just shows a black background.

[image]

I have search for answers and followed them.

- I made sure that the render icon was on
- I unchecked the emitter box that is in the "particles system" tab
- I made a vertex group
- I also added a mask modifier

I just have no idea what to do for my particles to render.

[image]

Comment: Sorry about not having a link to my blender. Blender exchange isn't working and I dont know how 'pasteall.org works. So if anyone knows another site i can link my blender, please let me know. Much appreciate it XD

Comment: @eromod They are halo and on the 'particle system tab under emission I set them on volume, just in case you need to know that as well

Comment: Did you assign a material to the particle system? Not sure now, but you probably need a *Halo* typo of material assigned to the object

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still kinda new so what would the halo type of material be that I can assign it to my particles

Comment: Ok I'm doing right now, it will take a bit though.

Comment: Do you happen to know another site i can upload it because the blender-exchange isn't working for me

Comment: I am but it keeps telling me when it loads half way that "server responded with 0 code"

Comment: @user27472 Hi, I'm the owner/operator of Blend-Exchange, could you send me along some details of the error (how big the file you uploaded was, what browser and OS you were using as well as exact details of what the error looked like (including where it was displayed on the page). See here for details on how to reach me: http://giantcowfilms.com/contact/. Thanks :D

Comment: Enable [Alpha transparent](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hEz5E.png)

Answer (score 1):

I think I found your problem. Your compositing node setup looks like this:
[image]

You need to switch the node paths going into the Alpha Over node on the left so that it looks like this
[image]

I think that will solve your problem! Before you were layering the black background over the blue particles but if you switch them like in the second picture, the blue particles are going over the background!

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38333/background-image-shows-in-front-of-3d-objects-not-behind-them/38334#38334