# Ovelayed images show transparent in compositor

Tags: compositing-nodes, image

I am adding some overlay images in the compositor.
But when I add the images it appears to be transparent.
[image]
Why is my image appearing like this?

Comment: Maybe you ment to use a color MIX node instead of the ADD mode?`

Comment: That does not work, because when using a mix node I must reduce the value of the one image to increase the value of the other. (thanks for your suggestion though)

Comment: FIXED I must use an "Alpha over node!"

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38333/background-image-shows-in-front-of-3d-objects-not-behind-them/38334#38334 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49049/my-objects-are-semi-transparent-and-not-one-behind-the-other-in-the-compositor/49137#49137

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED I must use an "Alpha over node!"