# Compositing: how to render object on top of background?

Tags: compositing-nodes

I am doing an animation with a camera to add 3D elements to it (don't really know what it is called) when I press shift z to render my scene, things look great.

[image: I am doing an animation]

but when I try to actually render an image from my animation it only shows the monkey with the shadow, but no background.

[image]
I know that it has something to do with compositing nodes and stuff, but I am not sure how to works.. could someone please help?

A also I used the new shadow catcher thing to make the shadow appear.

Thank you.

Comment: read the following link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/38334/1853