# Rendering shadows on transparent background / converting model from cycles to internal render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, transparency, shadows

I'm trying to render a model over existing video footage. So I need to render the shadows on a transparent background so it can be superimposed on the footage. I know there is a way to do this in the blender render and not cycles but I'm getting stuck with this file. I can't get the model of the building to show up in the render, I think it has something to do with me converting this from cycles. And I can't get any shadows to be cast at all. I've attached a link to the .blend any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

[Blender File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DWULLjmHh5xEyaJO9NQWKvuWeMwH9kzl/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I fixed the model not showing up in the render. It was on a different layer. But I still can't get shadows to show up at all

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87286/add-object-and-shadow-over-a-background-using-the-compositor/87314#87314

Answer (score 0):

Someone commented with a different post with the answer, thanks!

[Render shadows over a transparent background in cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47569/render-shadows-over-a-transparent-background-in-cycles)

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118124/where-on-earth-is-the-mark-duplicate-ui