# Transparent rendered object over tracked background

Tags: rendering

I am ready to render my animation but it seems i have a problem with my texture of the object i animated. 
In the image u can see that the object is transparent and I can look trough it.
So what is the problem here?
[image]

This is the node setup.

[image]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It would help if you edited into your question a screen grab of your node set up (assuming Cycles).

Answer (score 3):

The default nodes created when you solve a scene with motion tracking and hit "Setup Tracking Scene" don't really work in all cases.

The problem is that the 3D scene with the transparent background is not added using an **Alpha Over** node on top of the background.

The basic nodes you need looks more like this:

[image]

Or maybe even something like this:

[image]

Comment: Related links: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38333/background-image-shows-in-front-of-3d-objects-not-behind-them/38334#38334 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87286/add-object-and-shadow-over-a-background-using-the-compositor/87314#87314

Comment: and [My objects are semi-transparent, and not one behind the other in the compositor](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49049/my-objects-are-semi-transparent-and-not-one-behind-the-other-in-the-compositor/49137#49137)