# Why does my 3D Object become transparent

Tags: rendering, tracking, motion-capture

[image]

When I click f12 the texture of my 3D object become like this. If I missed something please tell me. I'm newbie at motion track. It'll help a lot thanks :)

Comment: There is not enough information on the question to answer. Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information. We don't know how you set up your project, or the materials or compositing.

Comment: Maybe related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/108790/transparent-rendered-object-over-tracked-background/108876#108876

Answer (score 1):

You enabled option **shadow catcher**.  The **shadow catcher** is a specific option, used typically on floor planes in order to 'catch' shadows from lighting within the scene. It is useful for integrating a rendered object onto a photographic background.

[image]

You need to enable it on floor, not on object.

**See also**

[How to use shadow catcher](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=2&v=72KfX4kuJok)