# Object won't render over tracked background image

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, camera, tracking

I've been working on an animation trying to incorporate animation into the background images.I don't know the reason why it won't render the arm. I  tracked and solved the motion in the movie clip editor, and here's how it renders:

[image]

I'm using blender render and not cycles.Items that I figured probably aren't as important are blurred out a little, so it's easier to see what settings I have.

If anyone can help please do. Here are some settings of that part of the arm that shows up in the render as transparent:

[image] [image]
[image]

Thanks!
-CHorse

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my object not show up?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up)

Comment: Also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank/

Comment: Please add more detail to the question. Did you do motion tracking in the video clip editor? Is that what you mean by camera trace? It is not clear what you did. Can you show the nodes you have going in the compositor? Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information.

Comment: Read the following link and report back if this helps: [Transparent rendered object over tracked background](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/108790/transparent-rendered-object-over-tracked-background/108876#108876)

Comment: Well the problem is I don't know if you guys saw but it's in blender render. I didn't use any nodes, and I don't intend to switch to cycles because blender render worked fine for my other animation, I don't know why it's acting up now.

Comment: I'm asking about the compositor, not shader nodes.  And we still have no clue of what you mean by "camera trace" or how you set your project... you have to help those who are trying to help you. Did you read through the links in the comments?

Comment: Well in the movie clip editor it has something that solves for the camera path.
and as for links; I checked them out but it didn't help because I either had the setting active or it was for cycles, which didn't work out because I'm on blender render. What's the compositor?

Comment: When you solve a scene in motion tracking, and set the 3D environment. Blender creates nodes in the **Compositor**. I suspect your problem is there. https://i.stack.imgur.com/dC9fZ.png

Comment: why don't you have any texture file loaded in you texture settings?

Comment: @cegaton I put it up

Comment: ok, now read thiks link again: [Transparent rendered object over tracked background]( https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/108790/transparent-rendered-object-over-tracked-background/108876#108876) Remember that you have to press f12 to render otherwise the compositor has no information to work with. The nodes on the left should not be empty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transparent rendered object over tracked background](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/108790/transparent-rendered-object-over-tracked-background)