# Motion Tracking Invisible Object Not Doing Its work properly

Tags: rendering, tracking, shadows

Okay, I am not very good in the motion tracking sector, but basically, the shadows are very weak and I have no idea on how to change that, they are so weak to the point of being invisible at some parts when I render it. I am using 2.8 version. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your question is unclear.Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project. [Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand your scene, settings and the results you are getting.

Comment: Maybe related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/108790/transparent-rendered-object-over-tracked-background/108876#108876

Comment: Explain what's unclear?

Comment: No one else but you knows what you have done so far. It's hard to guess your settings, compositing nodes or the result you are getting, or you mean by "weak", etc. If you are not getting answers is because there is not enough information on your post in order to help you.

Comment: Shadows are really weak, almost invisible, because the shadow catcher isn't working properly, and I didn't touch any setting, all I did was pressing "Set Up Tracking Scene"...

Comment: Yes, not helpful. Blender has updated since then, it uses shadow catcher now...

Comment: I know, and I did give the info you asked me, it's just not helpful because it's not for the updated version. Thanks.