# Motion track image does't appear in render

Tags: rendering, tracking

[image]

I make sure the transparent checkbox was hit, but the only thing it appears in render is this.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The images used in the workspace are for reference only.

Go to compositing workspace, check *Use Nodes* and then<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> > *Image Sequence*.

Then <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> > Viewer and connect image sequence to the viewer and *Composior* node. If the image size doesn't fit, you can try to use *Scale* node, I am not that sure if that's the right name

The basic node setup for tracking is described here:

[Transparent rendered object over tracked background](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/108790/transparent-rendered-object-over-tracked-background/108876#108876)