# Car model does not render after using motion tracking, but its visible in viewport

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, tracking

[image]I am fairly new to Blender.(I am an experienced Maya 3D artist)[image] I'm using version 2.83 on an iMac. I have rendered simple 3D models before using blender and the Eevee engine. But I need to test motion tracking and photo realistic 3D car rendering for work. I have followed a good motion tracking and rendering tutorial on youtube, but since I have the motion tracking figured out and scaled correctly with my car model, it will not render. If I add a sphere to the scene it will not render. The only thing that shows up in my renders is the image sequence background that I used for the motion tracking. I have checked my render layers, the car is render enabled. The Cycles render engine is selected. I can see the car in the viewports, but it never renders! Can someone please help? I am attaching a screenshot.

Comment: Did you press f12 to render? Also read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/108876/92768

Answer (score 0):

When you press "setup tracking scene" after solving the camera movement, blender creates two collections: a foreground (with a cube as reference) and a background (a plane to catch shadows).

You can safely delete the background one if you don't need a shadow catcher.

See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/108876/92768

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I think I figured out the problem. It seems that I started my motion tracking project having already had a car model in my scene. When I followed the motion tracking tutorial it disabled the render abilities for the car model somehow. So I started the tutorial again with an empty scene, and then appended my car model into the scene after the tracking and camera solving. This worked! I can now render my car and its shadows.

Comment: @LemonHat all that you need to do is incorporate the collection where the car is to the rendered collections, or add a node in the compositor to have the contents of the collection where the car is so that the information can be available for compositing. No need to do things over.