# Blender VFX Shadow Catcher Screw up

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, camera, tracking, shadowcatcher

I have been working on a small short film that has a small section of VFX work, However; when I was rendering a test result to see if everything was working the way it needed to, the render did not seem to go as planned. As seen below, the Robot has no casting shadow, instead, it has a plane with a half opacity it seems, anyone that have done VFX before in blender would know that blender creates a plane for you and makes it a shadow catcher. idk whats going on.[image] if anyone could help that would be great :)

Thanks, -Adam

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87286/add-object-and-shadow-over-a-background-using-the-compositor/87314#87314

Comment: Sorry but this still doesn't answer my question... The layout on that post is different and not using Motion Tracking.

Comment: The principle is the same. You set the plane as shadow catcher and overlay the 3d scene over the background image using alpha over.

Comment: Wow thank you very much Cegaton, i'm still kinda new to this motion tracking with blender...