# Trying to set transparency on the viewer Node

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, node-editor, shaders, transparency

First time posting in blender but it's important. Thank you for your support.

I have a model which have a Mix Shader with Glass and transparency shaders mixed, both with a texture as Color.

When I use the nodes for compositing, the glass of the model doesn't transparent with the background. If I set to Multiply, all the model multiplies and I can see through the glass, but cannot with Mix.

[image: This is the plane]
[image: And this is the Node View]
[image: The plane with the material]

Someone can help me with these? Any advice for handle those situations? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need an ID mask, just use a transparent background for your scene and then composite using alpha over.

Enable film transparent,

[image]

Then use alpha over to combine the rendered image with the background:

[image]

The transparency from the glass should work fine.

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38333/background-image-shows-in-front-of-3d-objects-not-behind-them/38334#38334

Comment: Yes! That's what exactly I was searching and worked perfectly!! Thank you very much! So, can I make shadows over the person? Camera is positioned to the viewport and idk if it's difficult to model a mesh for doing shadows with this perspective. Thank you again, very very much

Comment: You need to create some 3d object that acts as a shadow catcher, so that it will be transparent except for the shadow. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/87314/1853 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47569/render-shadows-over-a-transparent-background-in-cycles/47989#47989