# Camera Tracking Shadow

Tags: camera, tracking, shadows, movie-clip-editor, compositing-nodes

I was following this tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CVPcT0dJmoY&t=346s
 which is a bit old but I was able to get it through the camera tracking and to the point of adding 3d objects to the scene via the "setup tracking scene" in the movie clip editor.  However, while the cube (layer 1) has a shadow cast on it, there is no shadow cast on the ground (layer 2).
[image]
It seems to cast it onto the plane but not onto the background image.  In the tutorial, there is a problem with his compositing but mine seems to be set up correctly but I still can't figure out how to fix it. Can anyone see the problem?  I checked his compositing nodes and they seem to be the same arrangement as mine.  Can anyone help me?

Here is a screenshot of my attempt to use the Blender Render fix suggested in one of cegaton's links
[image]

I switched over to Cycles and used shadow catcher which worked on one level, but now I'm stumped again.  I can see the shadow in the render window but when I render it out to an animation there was no shadow.  In the screenshot below you can see the rendered output at the bottom with no shadow and the render window in the top right with a shadow.  I rendered it as a .png sequence. Not sure what I did wrong. Thanks for your help so far and I hope you can help me figure this out.
[image]

Comment: Are you sure you haven't switched foreground and background? Your adding the background renderlayer on top of everything else.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/87314/1853

Comment: Read also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/108790/transparent-rendered-object-over-tracked-background/108876#108876

Comment: Are they incorrect in the screenshot I took?  They are set up automatically by Blender when you enact the function "setup tracking scene".  I might have messed them up myself but they weren't working in the first place.  I'm learning this aspect of blender for the first time so this is a little foreign to me.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry cegaton, I typed my last reponse before seeing yours. I'll check out those links.

Comment: I tried to reset my nodes like the link that's a Blender Render and I didn't get any better results.  Specifically, I tried to reset them like the node tree that is already similar to mine.  I'd post a screenshot of my node tree currently but I don't know how to do that in the comments.  I'll try it again with the simpler set up and try the Cycles links version but I just don't understand the basics of why my set up didn't work.  This is a function that I really want to understand so I can use it in a specific production I'm working on.  Anyway, thanks again for all your help already.

Comment: I just edited my post to show the first attempt at a fix based on the suggestions I got.

Comment: I edited my post again and now have another issue.  If anyone wants to look at the new issue, keep in mind I switched to cycles and am using shadow catcher.