# Object Becoming Transparent When Rendered

Tags: rendering, texturing

When I preview the render of my shot the skateboard/skateboard texture is transparent when it should be solid. The second picture is what it should(?) look like. As to how I set the scene up; I motion tracked the clip and used a floor that was generated by that. I imported the skateboard model. Using cycles render I made a new material and set the color to image texture and used the texture image that came with the model. After following a few tutorials a set up the three nodes belows.
Any help is greatly appreciated.[image: blender_screenshot][image: blender_Screenshot]

[image]

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project. Add an image of the nodes used in the compositor.

Comment: The floor should be transparent or setup as shadowcatcher. Read: [Add object and shadow over a background using the compositor](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87286/add-object-and-shadow-over-a-background-using-the-compositor/87314#87314)