# 2.8 Eevee Composite Object over background lacking Transparency

Tags: compositing-nodes, image, eevee-render-engine

Can anyone provide instructions on how to composite my object over an image background in 2.8, Eevee render?  The problem is that the object is does not have transparency around it.  I set a bounding box but that only shrunk the background.  I've looked for transparency settings in the the shader and in the renderer and in the compositor but am not finding anything.  I've tried both Alpha over and Mix.  See attached screenshot.  I want just that green cube floating in the air near the dude's head (just experimenting), minus the dark gray around the green cube.
[image]

Comment: Don't use the mix node, use alpha over [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiWXQ.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Background image shows in front of 3D objects, not behind them.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38333/background-image-shows-in-front-of-3d-objects-not-behind-them)

Comment: Thanks folks, that is what I had tried first, and reverting back to that leaves me with the same problem still.  The difference I notice is that your objects have a Transparent background in the Render Layer and mine does not.  How do I set that for my object in Eevee?  That might seem like a simple question, I am fairly new to Blender.  Thanks!

Comment: @S.Magnusson Would you check the date of the question :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell *Alpha Over* what is transparent - black in the Jupiter .jpg image is set to be transparent in this example and *ColorRamp* helps adjust what is transparent and what is not. The *Transform* node is for the position and scale of it.

[image: Compositing]