# How to add background image?

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes

I want to add a background image to a render through the compositing, nodes but I can't seem to figure it out. How can I do this?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38333/background-image-shows-in-front-of-3d-objects-not-behind-them/38334#38334

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/38464/92768