# How do I add my character animation in blender, to a videoclip?

Tags: 3d-view, export, camera, compositing-nodes

I created a robot and animated the movement with the camera going around it in blender. I also got the video footage from a game (gta v) where I wanna put the robot (also with the camera turning around an empty spot where the robot would be).

Could someone explain briefly or more in detail (depending how much time u have) how I can put the robot there and make it look like it's really standing on that spot on the game footage? I'm assuming the camera rotation from blender, and from the game footage isn't the exact same angle so would that be a problem?

I can work with after effects and premiere pro but don't know much about blender. Youtube didn't help much on this one either so any help would be amazing!

Comment: Start here: [Realistic rendering of mesh together with image](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69832/realistic-rendering-of-mesh-together-with-image/69862#69862)

Comment: Read also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38333/background-image-shows-in-front-of-3d-objects-not-behind-them/38334#38334. The basic idea is that you render the foreground element with an alpha channel, and place it over the background using an Alpha Over node. But the challenge is matching the speed of the camera movement with the camera in blender, You might need to learn to do *motion tracking*. Look online for a series of videos called "track, match, blend" by Sebastian Koenig

Comment: Search for "blender vfx" in youtube and you will find some good tutorials about this topic:
https://youtu.be/hymtATx1QXw  (Add CGI Characters to Live Footage | Blender 2.8 VFX Tutorial - a dancing robot in your living room), https://youtu.be/YzKR8QtcozM Disintegration Effect - VFX Blender Tutorial, https://youtu.be/bVUeRIY1E-M How to Make Lightsabers in Blender