# Motion tracking video will not appear in render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, video-sequence-editor, video

I'm trying to do some simple motion tracking in Blender and all I need is for the video I imported to show in the render. [image]
This is how I was told the nodes are supposed to be set up. I have my movie clip and my rendered layers.
[image]
But the render looks like this... I really would appreciate some help

Comment: Enable the *Transparent* option under *Properties > Render (Camera Icon) > Film* to get your cube layer rendered properly. BTW: Suggest take the [tour] to learn about how this site works, cheers.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCHH

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38452/cycles-not-rendering-image-or-movie-clip-used-as-background-in-the-viewport/38464#38464, https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38333/background-image-shows-in-front-of-3d-objects-not-behind-them/38334#38334, https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49049/my-objects-are-semi-transparent-and-not-one-behind-the-other-in-the-compositor/49137#49137